# ValueConverter для FontWeight у ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableObject}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

`MyObservableObject` это: 
`ObservableCollection<MyClass>` где MyClass это объекты типа:

```
class MyClass
{
  public string Value {get; set;}
  public string OtherValue {get; set;}
}
```

`ComboboxItemStyle` это стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight">
      <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource MyFontConverter}"/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Соотвественно, класс конвертера *MyFontConverter* переводит объекты  `MyClass` в *FontWeight*
Это прекрасно работает для ComboBoxItems.

Но мне надо установить FontWeight у самого ComboBox, в зависимости от того элемента, который отображается.
Пытаюсь делать так:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableObject}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource MyFontConverter}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>          
</ComboBox>
```

Но в конвертер попадает сама ViewModel

Comment: `FontWeight="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PathConverter}}"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо большое! Помогло :) Можете заменить PathConverter на MyFontConverter, для соответствия вопросу и оформить, как ответ. Поставлю, как принятый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
FontWeight="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyFontConverter}}"
```

Или так:

```
FontWeight="{Binding MyObservableObject/, Converter={StaticResource MyFontConverter}}"
```